# Performing right shift and bit masking on binary fraction in python

Tags: python, binary, bit-shift, bitmask

I am looking for a way in python to perform right shift and bit masking on a binary number which has a fraction part as well. For e.g., if there are 1 integer and 2 fraction bits in the number, then number 0b101 corresponds to 1.25 in decimal. First, I want to know the pythonic way to represent this number in python.

Second, I want to perform 1 right shift on this number (0b101>>1) so that the resultant number will be 0b010 which will be 0.5 in decimal. Is there an intrinsic and pythonic way in python to perform this operation. Similarly, how to mask and get a specific bit from the binary number?

Presently, for shift I am multiplying the number by 2**-x, x is the number of right shifts. I cannot think a similar operation I can perform for bit mask.

Comment: I don't think you should be attempting bitmask operations on floating-point numbers. It is true that 0b101 is one way to represent 1.25 on paper but that is not how it is stored in memory, because the leading 1-bit is implied. Your operation will fail on unnormalized floating point numbers unless you check for that first. Your code will be very hard to read and probably slower than multiplying by powers of 2. There are probably several other good reasons why not.

Comment: Operator `>>` *is* the python right shift operator.

Comment: @BoarGules for my project I want to extract the particular bit present within fraction part. Even though I cannot perform the available bit-operators in python, I was looking for a way to extract the bit. Only way I could find was to first convert the number to integer by multiplying it by 2**number_of_fraction_bits, and then extracting the required bit. Don't know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: I'd encapsulate everything in a class. Do you get the same answers to everything if you only work with integers, then divide by 2^n afterwards (where n is the number of "floating point bits")?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yes I do get same value as right shifted operation when  I divide by 2^n.

Answer (score 2):

If you really must get directly at the internal representation of a float you can use `struct`, like this:

```
>>> import struct
>>> a = 1.25
>>> b = struct.pack('>d',a) 
>>> b
b'?\xf4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'  # the ? means \x3f, leftmost 7 bits of exponent
>>> a.hex()
'0x1.4000000000000p+0'
```

You can mask the bit you want out of the bytestring that `struct.pack()` returns.

*[edit]* The question mark representing `\x3f` is because the default output representation of a bytestring is a *string* and Python will where possible show an ascii character, not two hex digits.

*[edit]* This representation is in principle platform-dependent, but in practice it isn't, because virtually every computer (even IBM mainframes nowadays) has a floating-point processor that uses this format.

Finding out which bit you want may be something of a challenge.

```
>>> c = struct.pack('>d',a/2)
>>> c
b'?\xe4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> (a/2).hex()
'0x1.4000000000000p-1'
```

As you can see, division by 2 is not quite the simple one-bit shift to the right that your question seems to suggest you are expecting. In this case, the division by 2 has decremented the exponent by 1 (from `0x3ff` to `0x3fe`; 1023 to 1022) and left the bit pattern of the fraction (`0x4000`) unchanged. The exponent appears large because it is biased by 1023.

The main difficulties are

1. Sign, exponent and fraction don't align to byte boundaries, but to nybble boundaries (sign plus exponent: 12 bits; fraction: 52 bits)
2. The number is normalized so that it has no leading zeroes (much as scientific notation in decimal is normalized so that it has no leading zeroes) and, since everyone knows it's there, the leading 1 is not stored.

I can recommend the [Wikpedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) on this subject: it has lots of useful examples.

But I suspect that you don't really want to get at the internal representation of a float. Instead, you want a *fixed*-point binary class, without pesky binary exponents, that works much the same as you would do it on paper, and where division by a power of 2 really does reflect as a shift of so many bits to the right.

Depending on how much work you want to put into it, you could do this by defining a `FixedBinary` class as a subclass of `numbers.Real`, with the integer portion internally represented by one `int` and the fractional component by another `int`, and the sign by a third `int`, so that 1.25 would be represented as `(1, int(0.25 * 65536), +1)` (or some other power of 2).

This also shows you the simplest way to get a bit representation of your fraction.

*[edit]* I recommend storing the sign separately. You could store it in the integer portion, or the fraction, or both, but all have disadvantages.

1. If you store it in the sign of the fraction, the twos-complement
   representation of negative integers will give you difficulty when
   you want to mask your bits.
2. If you don't store it in the sign of the fraction there will be no way to
   represent -0.5.
3. If you don't store it in the sign of the integer portion there will be no way to represent -1.0.

A multiplicand of 65536 will give you 4 decimal digits of accuracy. You can increase it if you want more. I also recommend that you store your fraction in the rightmost bits and simply ignore the leftmost bits. In other words, be content with the binary point being in the middle of the `int`, don't insist on it being on the left. That is because you will need headroom to the left of the binary point when you do multiplication.

Implementing your own numeric class is a considerable amount of work, though.

Comment: there were some new concepts for me in your answer, so I took some time to understand them. The part where you mentioned about struct.pack() and IEEE 754 floating point notation. I believe this is to show how the binary fraction number should be saved in memory. Is this binary representation platform dependent or python always saved floats this way? Also, I did not understand why there is '?' in binary representation? The gist, I get, from the first part of your answer is that I cannot work with these floating point representations for my fixed point shifting operations.

Comment: About your suggestion to create my class defining my own operations for fixed point using number.Real, I will try that and accept your answer once I do that. At present I am first quantizing the number to closest binary representation and then using multiplicaiton by 2^n, n is number of fraction bits, to convert the fraction to integer. Perform bit mask on this binary representation of the integer number. Then, convert the integer back to fixed point by multiplying 2^-n.

Comment: I've edit the answer to answer the supplementary questions in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can work using fxpmath.

Info about this package is at:
https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath

For your example:

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

x = Fxp('0b0101', signed=True, n_word=4, n_frac=2)

print(x)

y = x >> 1

print(y)

# example of AND mask
z = x & Fxp('0b0110', signed=True, n_word=4, n_frac=2)
print(z.bin())
```

outputs:

> 1.25
>   0.5
>   0100